# How to add each array element into aN array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

By using JS, I am trying to get a 2d array where I have an array as shown below :

```
   array [ "2016/03/31", "2016/03/30", "2016/03/29", "2016/03/28", "2016/03/27", "2016/04/01"]
```

Looking for output as

```
    array [
         {'date':'2016/03/22'},  
         {'date':'2016/03/23'},
         {'date':'2016/03/24'},
         {'date':'2016/03/25'},
         {'date':'2016/03/26'},
         {'date':'2016/03/27'},   
         {'date':'2016/03/28'},
         {'date':'2016/03/29'}
       ];
```

> JS

```
    function getarryDates (list)
    {
        var aryDates = [];
        var Dates_ary = [];
        $.each(list, function(i, e) {              
              Dates_ary[0] =       aryDates.push("'date:'"+ e);  
        });
        return Dates_ary;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

Try like this

```
var newList=list.map(function(x){ return {'date':x} })
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/gaf6pxtp/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with minimal changes, you can do this:

```
function getarryDates (list)
{
    var aryDates = [];
    var Dates_ary = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {              
          Dates_ary[i] = {"date": e };  // <-- use index 'i' and 
                                        // create object instead of str.
    });
    return Dates_ary;
 }
```

However, the solution with `map` is better: it is DRY, easier to understand and easier to maintain.